# Check is sunday from datepicker dialog

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Hi I'm new to android i'm doing one project in my project i want to check is sunday from selected date in datepicker dialog please help me

Comment: I got it Thank You Mike M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this...

```
if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY){
//task related to sunday
}else{
//tasks related to other days
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much saurabh gupta

Comment: @Muthukumar mine pleasure...happy coding....